# How to check the type of an EclipseNode?

Tags: eclipse-jdt, lombok

Given an `EclipseNode node`, what's the difference between:

```
node.getKind() == Kind.FIELD
// or
node.getKind() == Kind.TYPE
```

and

```
node.get() instanceof FieldDeclaration
// or
node.get() instanceof TypeDeclaration
```

?

Do both guarantee a safe cast of the `ASTNode`?

Answer (score 1):

In JDT int-based kinds are mainly used in switch statements, which are more efficient than the corresponding cascade of instanceof checks. Kind constants in `ASTNode` clearly state the type to which they correspond.

`EclipseNode` is not from JDT, I cannot answer this part.